# Is this a water stop valve?

Tags: plumbing, dishwasher

[image]

Hi folks. Is this a water stop valve? I have attached my dishwasher water line to it but unscrewing the screw doesn't seem to do anything. Should I look for another valve? Thanks...

[image]

Here's a pic from the side, as req. No water flow atm. Just moved in so don't really know too much about the plumbing...

Comment: Shut off valves usually have some type of handle, not just a screw.  Can you post a picture looking from the side?  Right now it looks like a pipe/pot mender screw(to seal hole).

Comment: I wonder if that's plugging a hole for a saddle valve... but no, it certainly doesn't look like a valve itself.

Comment: Remove the screw entirely and take a closer look at what it was screwed into. You'll probably find that it's a shaft with flats on either side. Grip the shaft with pliers and give it a 90-degree turn (not sure which direction).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a 90°, ¼ turn valve. The part marked with a red square below is the valve shutoff. You'll find it's circular, but with two flattened sides. If the flats are in-line with the pipe, it's on, 90° to it [like now] & it's off. The screw is to hold the missing handle on, not for the water.
You should be able to turn it with a wrench, grips or even pliers if it's loose enough.
It *might* need a squirt of oil, WD40 etc, as it looks a bit corroded, but they're usually quite resilient even if they do get a touch of verdigris - the cold feed especially can attract condensation, so they're pretty much proofed against it.

You might be able to get a replacement handle at a local DIY store, they're pretty universal sizes, choice of colours - red or blue; hot or cold.

I wouldn't worry about the joint having been PTFE-wrapped. The top part has obviously been holding pressure well all the time since it was fitted. Do check your new attachment is good once the water's been turned on, and all is good to go.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, great detective work Tetsujin, much appreciated.... I turned it a little with a spanner, as suggested, and some water came out from the valve shutoff area under pressure, so I turned it back... Is that what you'd expect?

Comment: What do you consider the 'valve shutoff area'? Basically, if water comes out of anywhere other than straight through the pipe to the dishwasher, the unit's faulty & needs replacing. [Unless it's just round the edges of the nylon fitting, in which case it might just need tightening - they say 'hand tight' but an extra 1/8 of a turn wouldn't go amiss.]

Answer (score 2):

Is water flowing through it now or is the water blocked?

That does look like some sort of shutoff valve with the handle broken off. It's also installed wrong because it's a compression fitting on to a copper pipe and should not have any white plumbing tape on it.

I would replace it with a new valve. The only problem you might have is if there's not another shutoff valve for that pipe, you'll need to shut off the water to the house until you install a new valve.